# I got many errors in my function swift 2

Tags: swift, swift2

I have one project that write with swift 1 but now I run with Xcode 7.2 (swift 2)
but I don't know why I got many errors.

I can fix one problem in my previous question but I have big problem and I so tired.

this is my code :

```
public func generate() -> AnyGenerator <(String, JSON)> {
        switch self.type {
        case .Array:
            let array_ = object as! [AnyObject]
            var generate_ = array_.generate()
            var index_: Int = 0
            return AnyGenerator<(String, JSON)> {
                if let element_: AnyObject = generate_.next() {
                    return ("\(index_++)", JSON(element_))
                } else {
                    return nil
                }
            }
        case .Dictionary:
            let dictionary_ = object as! [String : AnyObject]
            var generate_ = dictionary_.generate()
            return AnyGenerator<(String, JSON)> {
                if let (key_, value_) = generate_.next() {
                    return (key_, JSON(value_))
                } else {
                    return nil
                }
            }
        default:
            return AnyGenerator<(String, JSON)> {
                return nil
            }
       }
 }
```

please guide me about these errors!!!
[image]

Comment: The error message says that the function takes no arguments. CMD-click on the symbol to look up the declaration.

Comment: @vadian how to fix it???

Comment: If the function doesn't want arguments delete them and use just `AnyGenerator()`

Comment: Unrelated to this question, but you already got some answers to your previous questions. Don't forget to *accept* helpful answers by clicking on the check mark. That marks the problem as solved, and gives some reputation points to you and to the author of the answer.

Comment: @vadian you tell me I delete (String,JSON) from AnyGeneretor???

Comment: please tell me with code

Comment: @Martin R please help me

Comment: `AnyGenerator` is intended to be abstract. You can't instantiate it directly. I don't know how this code ever compiled.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 2, the global function

```
public func anyGenerator<Element>(body: () -> Element?) -> AnyGenerator<Element>
```

is used to create a (type-erased) generator from a given
closure:

```
public func generate() -> AnyGenerator <(String, JSON)> {

    // ...
    return anyGenerator {
        if let element_: AnyObject = generate_.next() {
            return ("\(index_++)", JSON(element_))
        } else {
             return nil
        }
    }
}
```